# OnException - twice call

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have BaseController class with OnException handler.

```
public class ApiBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = ...
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

My inherited controllers have custom HandleJsonError on their actions:

```
public class ApiCompanyController : ApiBaseController
{
    [HttpPost, HandleJsonError]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        // ...
        if (...) throw new DependentEntitiesExistException(dependentEntities);
        // ...
    }
}
```

HandleJsonError is:

```
public class HandleJsonError : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
    {
        // ...
        exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

When DependentEntitiesExistException exception is risen, both base controller's and HandleJsonError's OnException handlers are called. How can I make not call base controller OnException after HandleJsonError's OnException finished?

Comment: Can't you check in the base controller if the exception has already been handled, like `if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled) return;` ?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. so simple :) thank you. If you post it as answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check on your base controller if the exception has already been handled. If so, skip the method execution:

```
public class ApiBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do not continue if exception already handled
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled) return;

        //Error handling logic
        filterContext.Result = ...
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

PS. Happy new year! :)